# Precision for semilogyaxis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a `semilogyaxis` with `log ticks with fixed point` option.  What I don't like is that the label for `1.013` is truncated to `1.01`.  I tried to sort that out with `/pgf/number format/precision` key, but it did not help.  Do you have any idea what went wrong?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[log ticks with fixed point,xmin=0,xmax=400,ymin=1E-5,ymax=1E4,ytick={1E-5,6.1E-3,1.013,221,1E4},yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision=4}]

\end{semilogyaxis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `/pgfplots/log ticks with fixed point` prints numbers using this:

```latex
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/number format}{fixed relative, precision=3}
```

However, it accepts an argument which is fed as options to `\pgfmathprintnumber` and can override these defaults. Thus, your problem should normally be solved using `log ticks with fixed point={precision=4}`. Unfortunately, due to—as far as I understand it—numerical errors caused by the relatively small number of significant digits in computations done with the PGF `fpu` library, the lowest y tick would then show as 0.000009999 instead of 0.00001, which isn't very pleasant.

In order to solve this problem, I propose two solutions based on `/pgfplots/log number format code` (I'd favor the former).

## Using the `fixedpointarithmetic` Ti*k*Z library

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
  log number format code/.code={%
    \begingroup
      \pgfset{fixed point arithmetic,
              number format/.cd, fixed relative, precision=4}%
      \pgfmathparse{exp(#1)}%
      \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
    \endgroup
  },
  xmin=0, xmax=400,
  ymin=1E-5, ymax=1E4,
  ytick={1E-5,6.1E-3,1.013,221,1E4},
  ]
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Direct computation with the `fpu` Ti*k*Z library

`/pgfplots/log ticks with fixed point` already uses the `fpu` Ti*k*Z library, but it computes y ticks as exp(*n*ln(10)) for the relevant values of *n*. The chain of computations—one multiplication *then* exponentiation—leads to errors due to the small number of significant digits in `fpu` computations (TeX `\dimen` registers are used to represent the mantissa). The code below has slightly better numeric precision: it computes exp(*x*), where *x* is the natural logarithm of the tick value, provided as the argument of `/pgfplots/log number format code`. Less computations leads to less accumulation of numerical errors. This way, the result is satisfactory too—it is identical to the above screenshot.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
  log number format code/.code={%
    \begingroup
      \pgfset{fpu, number format/.cd, fixed relative, precision=4}%
      \pgfmathparse{exp(#1)}%
      \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
    \endgroup
  },
  xmin=0, xmax=400,
  ymin=1E-5, ymax=1E4,
  ytick={1E-5,6.1E-3,1.013,221,1E4},
  ]
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

P.S.: dont forget to set the `pgfplots` compatibility level (as I did here with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`).

Comment: OK, as a patch, I put 1.0001E-5 for the lowest y value

Comment: I have provided two solutions that don't exhibit the numerical accuracy problem due to the small number of significant digits in `fpu` computations.