# I encountered the following problems when using foreach:

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, calculations

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in{0,0.1,...,0.5}{
       \node[] at (20*\x,0) {\x};
       }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in{0,0.125,...,0.5}{
       \node[] at (20*\x,0) {\x};
       }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

it is normally.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Tex.SE. This is due to an rounding error. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446027/224762) for a full explanation.

Comment: Just use integers in `in{1, ..., 10}` whenever possible. You can always divide later

Comment: In binary representation numbers of the form n * 2^-m are exact. Whereas n * 10^-m have inherent rounding errors in binary representation. I don't know pfg internal representation, but since 0.125, 0.25 do not give rounding errors I suppose internal representation is binary.

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to TeX.SE. As said in comments, this is a precision issue due to how TikZ performs floating point computations (it uses TeX `\dimen` registers by default). Since the computed numbers are *very close* to the desired ones, you just need to use `\pgfmathprintnumber` in order to typeset the numbers rounded to the desired precision:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0, 0.1, ..., 0.5} {
    \node at (20*\x, 0) {%
      \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=1]{\x}%
  };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bottom line: computation is one thing, often not perfectly accurate. Number formatting is another thing that `\pgfmathprintnumber` does well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer！ I already understand

Answer (score 8):

As well as the precision of the displayed number (as answered in the other solutions), there is the issue with the missing node.  In the first foreach loop the last node is not displayed because PGF thinks that the next value is `0.50003` which is more than `0.5` so is outside the bounds of the loop.

As Symbol1 said in the comments, it is best to use integers in the loop when using the `...` syntax to ensure that this sort of thing doesn't happen.  This then means that the coordinate calculation needs changing, but this is easy to incorporate.  Slightly more complicated is computing the displayed number.  This can be done either in the node text itself using `pgfmathparse{\x/10}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}` or it can be done in the foreach loop itself (which is more useful if you are going to use the number more than once).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/610368/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in{0,0.1,...,0.5}{
       \node[] at (20*\x,0) {\x};
       }
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach[evaluate=\x as \displayx using \x/10] \x in{0,1,...,5}{
       \node[] at (2*\x,0) {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=1]{\displayx}};
       }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Loops with displayed values]

Comment: Good point, you have my upvote! ;-)

Comment: @frougon And you have mine!

Answer (score 7):

Borrowing and adapting the technique from frougon, [Precision for semilogyaxis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531694/precision-for-semilogyaxis/531697#531697)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in{0,0.1,...,0.5}{
       \node[] at (20*\x,0) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Note that we only need to round the input numbers here (which are computed by the `\foreach` statement with imperfect precision *before* your `\pgfset{fixed point arithmetic,...}` kicks in); so, the `\pgfmathparse{\x}` step is useless and might even result in a loss of precision in some situations (depending on what was in `\x` before). On the other hand, `\pgfmathprintnumber` parses the input number  with `\pgfmathfloatparsenumber`, which “allows arbitrary precision” (as written in the documentation of `\pgfmathprintnumber`). :-)

Comment: @frougon I have edited, hopefully capturing the essence of your comment.  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: That's better, but the `\pgfset{fixed point arithmetic}` is still useless here, AFAICS: no computation whatsoever is performed with this engine! The only thing we need to do here is some rounding before typesetting the number... which is what my answer does.